# Application suddenly hangs after updating mysql rds from 5.7 to 8.0.35

Tags: mysql, .net, iis, amazon-rds

I'm having some strange behaviour on my applications after upgrading my RDS MySQL from 5.7 to 8.0.35

Here's the full story:

I have an EC2 with IIS running some .NET (4.7.2) applications.
They were running fine for years with an MySQL 5.7 on RDS. Some days ago, I upgraded the MySQL version to 8.0.35.

To work with this version, I also had to change my MySQL.Client connector dll.
Everything seems to work fine, but sporadically (1~2 times a day), my applications hangs and never load. There's no application error, neither MySQL errors, the logs are clean. Perhaps, one thing that I notice that may be related to it, is these errors on Windows event viewer:

```
Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(System.ExceptionResource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+KeyCollection+Enumerator[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].MoveNext()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPoolManager+<CleanIdleConnections>d__29.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
```

```
StackTrace:    at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.KeyCollection.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPoolManager.<CleanIdleConnections>d__29.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
```

MySQL Global Status
https://pastebin.com/qGiy91f7

MySQL Global Variables:
https://pastebin.com/WWCFfAd5

```
SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables LIMIT 100000;

COUNT(*)    sum(data_length)    sum(index_length)   sum(data_free)
205         1051883876          196403200           354103488
```

```
SELECT 'SLEEPING time use', COUNT(*), SUM(time) FROM information_schema.processlist WHERE command="Sleep";

SLEEPING time use   COUNT(*)    SUM(time)
SLEEPING time use   6           5713
```

```
AWS Instance:
RDS: 
db.t2.micro
1 vCPU
1GB RAM
gp2 SSD 20GB
30% CPU utilization max (15% is the average)

EC2:
t2.micro
1 vCPU
1GB RAM
    EBS: 
    gp2 100GB
    300 IOPS
```

I really have no clue whats going on yet...
Anyone can help me to investigate? I can provide any additional info that may be usefull

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for posting your SGS and SGV workload analysis in process.  Will take a few hours. Hope to have suggestions in an Answer within 24 hours. 
What is your AWS instance type?  RAM size, Core/cpu count, Any SSD or NVME for data storage?  Approx date when you changed versions? Trouble free prior to version change?

Comment: Could you provide TEXT results of this query?  - SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables LIMIT 100000;

Comment: Could you also provide TEXT results of this query?  -  SELECT 'SLEEPING time use', 
COUNT(*),SUM(time)  
FROM information_schema.processlist 
WHERE 
command="Sleep";

Comment: Thank you for the reply!
I edited the question with the new info... I don't have much experience with AWS, but I think the info I gave is enough. Its nothing more than 2 t2.micro with all default settings...

I upgraded the database at 19/02/2024... no problems at all with the process

Answer (score 1):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your AWS t2.micro Parameter Groups

```
read_rnd_buffer_size=16384  # from 524288 to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 13,045.
thread_cache_size=12  # from 8 to reduce threads_created RPhr of 15
key_cache_age_threshold=7200  # to extend age-out and reduce key_reads RPS of 3.82
innodb_io_capacity=300  # from 200 to use more of your SSD IOPS
```

There are limited opportunities to improve performance on your 1GB, 1vcpu host.  When the budget permits consider more RAM and more CPU's.

In the meantime, managing your tables Date_Free space used will be to your advantage.  At this time the ratio of data space to data_free is about 40% average. If you want a query to Find the tables with more than 10% free space, let me know and provide an email address, please. View profile, please.

Comment: You rock man! I'll look into changing these parameters, will provide some update later!

I also found a "ClearAllPools()" on my code, that may be leading to the problem... I'm currently more than an entire day without any downtime, guess it is fixed, need to monitor it a little bit more

Comment: @user3159043 Please let us know your perception of performance after 48 hours uptime with the suggestions in use.  Better/Worse?

Comment: @user3159043 Any news you can share of your perception of performance at this time? Better or worse than on March 5, 2024? What was approximate date of last sudden hanging?